# Can I Use Sickening Grasp [Reserve Feat] During a Full Attack with a Two-Handed Weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, actions

Could a duskblade with vampiric touch as his first third level spell take the reserve feat sickening grasp, full round attack with his two handed weapon, then take a hand off and touch attack with sickening grasp? The reserve feat states it is a touch attack, not a standard action, so I believe this should work as a nice debuff for two or three rounds using your lower base attack shot.

Comment: A tip: when asking questions, make the title clearly indicate what the question is. This title is just two nouns with no verb, which doesn't convey anything useful to people reading the list of questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.**

*Complete Mage* states:

> Each reserve feat's primary benefit is a supernatural ability usable at will. Unless stated otherwise, it requires a standard action to activate and does not provoke attacks of opportunity.

The touch attack is merely a part of using the feat. Similar to [Inflict Light Wounds](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/inflictLightWounds.htm) allowing you to cast the spell, and then make a touch attack - as a part of the spell. Activating the feat itself, as a [supernatural ability](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#supernaturalAbilities), is a standard action, giving you a touch attack as part of that standard action.

**Note:** It would be allowed if someone/something gave you an extra [Standard Action](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#standardActions), like the [Belt of Battle](https://mission-from-sigil.obsidianportal.com/items/belt-of-battle). Taking your 'off-hand' off a two-hander is considered a free action.

Comment: Right you are, to bad it would have been a sweet one two punch.

Comment: @Nathtfm What also could be 'nice' would be to ask your DM if you could channel the Reserve Feat through your weapon. It would purely be a house rule - but would not be game breaking at all.